# Unexpected behavior shown by the function concat and push

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, concatenation

I was testing my code in goolge console and I found that `concat()` is not working as I have  illustrated below:

```
var a = ["a"]; //undefined
a.concat("b","c"); // ["a","b","c"]
```

Now when I push some other string then that string replaces the indexes of "b" and "c"

that is[continued]

```
 a.push("e","f"); // 3 
 a // ["a", "e","f"]
```

Did you notice 3 in the line where the string is pushed. It is interesting to me that at first we contact "b" and "c" and then, when I try to get value of say 1 index then it return `undefined`! and then, when we push `"e"` and `"f"` in the same array then these string replaces the indexes of concated string. Now the question is:

> 1) Why do these `concat` and `push` function show strange behavior?
>
> 2) Do this mean the failure of `cancat` function?
>
> 3) Is this`contact` function is just for nominal?

Comment: `.concat()` doesn't mutate the original. It makes a new Array. Please read documentation when you have questions about the native methods. [MDN `.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: you want push(), not concat()

Comment: Mind choosing an answer? :)

Comment: thanks to you too @Montagist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. Concat isn't modifying the array like you expect it to.

When you:

```
a.concat("b","c");
```

It returns an array of ["a","b","c"], but you aren't saving the reference (which you would do like this)

```
a = a.concat("b","c");
```

Some info [from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> concat does not alter this or any of the arrays provided as arguments but instead returns a shallow copy that contains copies of the same elements combined from the original arrays.

Comment: `push` modifies the array.

Comment: I'd suggest using Mozilla's docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat `The concat() method returns a new array ...`